Can we attach a init-container with strimzi kafka container?
Can we attach a init-container with strimzi kafka connect container? I want to copy some jars from another image (docker/my-sdk:9.1) to strimzi kafka connect container at runtime using init-container
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: debezium-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debezium-deployment-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debezium-deployment-app
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-container
          image: docker/my-sdk:9.1
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -r /data/TTMMM/sdk /shared-jars/']
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jar-volume
              mountPath: /shared-jars
      containers:
        - name: main-container
          image: docker/strimzi-kafka-image
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jar-volume
              mountPath: /home/TTMMM/


sure we can. What problem do you have with it?

Couldn't find image and command propeties in init-container property for Kind: KafkaConnect

you mean the one that is operated by the kafka operator. Well, i wouldnt try to get in its way. If you think it doesnt configure kafka to your liking. You could drop the operator and do whatever you wish. Replacing thast connect image may be enough in this  case though.

I meant attaching a init-container with  docker/strimzi-kafka-image container

From the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.

No, you cannot configure custom init containers like this. You should follow the Strimzi documentation and either build your own container image or use the Strimzi APi to build one for you.
